# No audio (I/O) Manjaro Linux KDE

Tags: linux, audio, kde, speakers, manjaro

I use my laptop for university and record lectures (I'm dyslexic). Until recently I believed my laptop was recording through the external microphone I got for it.  However, it always lists as microphone unplugged and defaults to the inbuilt microphone. This morning I tried to fix it using HDA-jack-retask. However, it seems I have completely disabled all audio, I have tried restarting.

I run manjaro linux KDE edition (latest version)
I had to install Pulse audio because it didn't come preinstalled
I have tried resetting to defaults via the built-in audio 
Checked if recording via pavucontrol and audio by attempting to play spotify and youtube (both of those jump around alot for no reason but no audio)

inxi -Fxi

```
System:    Host: tasty-laptop Kernel: 4.14.79-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.2.1 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.14.3 
           Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Purism product: Librem 13 v2 v: 2.0 serial: <root required> 
           Mobo: Purism model: Librem 13 v2 v: 2.0 serial: <root required> BIOS: coreboot v: 4.7-Purism-4 date: 03/20/2018 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT charge: 28.8 Wh condition: 41.3/44.7 Wh (92%) model: TPS S10 status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-6500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Skylake rev: 3 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 20744 
           Speed: 476 MHz min/max: 400/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 500 2: 500 3: 500 4: 500 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.3 driver: intel unloaded: modesetting resolution: 1600x900~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.4 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.14.79-1-MANJARO 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lite-On driver: ath9k v: kernel port: efa0 
           bus ID: 01:00.0 
           IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: 30:10:b3:00:00:6e 
           IP v4: 10.40.45.18/21 type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global 
           IP v6: fe80::a594:2f80:253c:2b62/64 type: noprefixroute scope: link 
           Device-2: Lite-On Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb bus ID: 1-3:3 
           WAN IP: 194.80.232.67 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 144.77 GiB (15.5%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS541010A9E680 size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 899.02 GiB used: 144.77 GiB (16.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 17.14 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 174 Uptime: 32m Memory: 15.59 GiB used: 1.73 GiB (11.1%) Init: systemd Compilers: gcc: 8.2.1 
           clang: 7.0.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.23 inxi: 3.0.27
```

arecord -l returns

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Screenshot of `alsamixer - c 0 --view Capture` and pulse open
https://forum.manjaro.org/uploads/default/optimized/3X/7/2/72e2e957318b1213d21fde2f787e132ffa2e422b_1_690x372.png

Added HDA-jack-retask screenshot no pins overided
https://forum.manjaro.org/uploads/default/optimized/3X/4/c/4c11a41b5a80af17a8b1cc9b389d27f665cf24de_1_690x388.png

cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xd112c000 irq 126
```

speaker-test -c 2 -l 1 -D hw:0

```
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy
```

Killed alsa via ksysgaurd
also killed pulse so it restarted the same way
now 
speaker-test -c 2 -l 1 -D hw:0

```
speaker-test 1.1.7

Playback device is hw:0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 64 to 1048576
Period size range from 32 to 524288
Using max buffer size 1048576
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 262144
was set buffer_size = 1048576
 0 - Front Left


 1 - Front Right


Time per period = 20.326463
```

But no audio is heard

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what all the above means, I am using Linux for less than 24 hours and so far many problems, one of them is no audio, here is what i did to get the audio working, that was by luck after couple hours fiddling around:

OS: Manjaro KDE latest version
Sound Card: Realtek HD sound or (ALC889)

1. Start Add/Remove Software Octopi
2. Search for PulseAudio Volume Control and install it
3. launch PuslseAudio control and go to configuration tab
4. High definition Audio Controller / choose **off**
5. Built-in Audio / choose **Analog Stereo Duplex (unplugged)(unavailable)**
6. Pray it works